# How to get the ticker-id of the main symbol that is currently selected, in a multi-security chart

Tags: pine-script

I have a watchlist-type chart, that is loading the tickers of a a fixed watchlist (top-10) via specific security calls. While processing the data for each security, I want to I get the name of currently select main-symbol of the chart.

Tried the syminfo.ticker function. It always refers to the symbol of the current security, and not the symbol selected in the main chart.

Comment: What do you mean by "symbol selected in the main chart"?

Comment: @vitruvius, I was referring to the the symbol which is currently selected as the chart's symbol. While for example, the chart shows the candles for XRP/USDT on the 15m time-frame, I call the security function top get BTC/USDT on a higher timeframe, in order to calculate some correlation-indicator.

Comment: After some deeper research, I am closing this question, by clarifying that in general, I found no problem in getting the tickerid of the main-chart's symbol, except of the case which I describe here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76278246/cannot-access-the-syminfo-tickerid-when-calling-request-security-with-dynamic