# Cannot access the syminfo.tickerid when calling request.security with "dynamic" customFunc

Tags: pine-script

I cannot get a security work correctly using a dynamic call to different custom functions, when this "dynamic" behavior depends on the syminfo.tickerid.
On the opposite, this dynamic call works ok, if it depends on e.g. timeframe.period

Is there any way to get around this? Or is it related to the nature of the security call?

Below is a simplifying example, displaying that behavior.
Normally, when selecting BITSTAMP:ETHUSD and 30-min timeframe on main-chart, two different lines should be drawn (red-EMA-3 and green-EMA-30)
Instead both 2 EMA-30 lines are drawn (green overwritting the red), indicating that syminfo.tickerid probably returns blank within the security call.

```
//@version=5
indicator("security, cust-func, ticker-id", "", true)

func1() => ta.ema(close,3)
func2() => ta.ema(close,30)
sec1 = request.security('BITSTAMP:BTCUSD', '60', str.upper(syminfo.tickerid ) == 'BITSTAMP:ETHUSD' ? func1():func2() ) 
sec2 = request.security('BITSTAMP:BTCUSD', '60', timeframe.period == '30' ? func1():func2() ) 

plot1b = plot(sec1,color=color.red)
plot2b = plot(sec2,color=color.green)
```

Answer (score 1):

Everything passed to the `expression` field in `request.security` function is evaluated directly on the symbol that the function specifies. Which means that `syminfo.tickerid` passed to `expression` will return the tickerid of the symbol from inside the security, and not the one on the chart. You can see it in action with this example code (change the inputs and note how data returned from security changes, while initial `expr` variable stays the same):

```
//@version=5
indicator("security, cust-func, ticker-id", "", true)

expr = syminfo.tickerid + ", " + timeframe.period
sec1 = request.security(input.symbol("BITSTAMP:ETHUSD"), input.timeframe('60'), expr) 

if barstate.islastconfirmedhistory
    label.new(bar_index, high, str.format("Expr: {0}\nsec1: {1}", expr, sec1))
```

To accomplish what you want, you can add several `security` calls, one for each expected `tickerid`, and then decide which security result to use based on the condition you want (outside of the security expression):

```
//@version=5
indicator("security, cust-func, ticker-id", "", true)

func1() => ta.ema(close,3)
func2() => ta.ema(close,30)
sec1 = request.security('BITSTAMP:BTCUSD', '60', func1()) 
sec2 = request.security('BITSTAMP:ETHUSD', '60', func2())

result = ticker.standard(syminfo.tickerid) == "BITSTAMP:ETHUSD" ? sec1 : sec2 

plot1b = plot(sec1,color=color.red)
plot2b = plot(result,color=color.green)
```

Comment: Clear enough and well understood  @beeholder . Thank you very much for the detailed explanation!